# API Authentication for user logged in to a Web App server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a Web App and a separate API (so that users can share their collected data with someone if they want to) using Ruby on Rails. The users can log in on the web app and fill data that should be posted to the API Server.

From everything I have read till now, I guess that I can use cookie based authentication to check whether the user is logged in to the Web App. Now let's say that the user wants to post data to the API Server. Since the user is authenticated to the Web App Server, how should the post request be made so that the API knows that it is getting the data from the specific user who is logged in. Also if the user wants to get data from the API that is private to him/her, how should the get request be made for this purpose?

Comment: What is the relation between your app and api? Do you mean javascript ajax requests for json data from logged in user or completely separate thing?

Comment: I want the API to be completely independent of the web app. The web app will collect some data about the logged in user. Now I want to send(POST) this data to the Restful API where it will be stored along with the username. How should I do it so that there are no security issues and only the signed in user can post data about itself.

Comment: @chan123 Do you share your model/business logic in both(web app server and API), I mean share the same database? Or they are independent of the database?

Comment: You shouldn't be using cookies in an API. OAuth was designed to solve the problem of authorizing clients to access resources.  I've provided an answer with code examples below.

Answer (score 13):

You could consider the doorkeeper gem for your API authorization.  I considered it but decided against it because of complexity and lacking documentation for my use cases. Put simply I couldn't get it working properly.

There is a good [article](http://pothibo.com/2013/07/authentication-with-warden-devise-less/) on authentication using warden without devise which should give you a good feel for the moving parts of an authentication system. Devise is not appropriate for API authentication and in fact Devise recently removed the one thing that could be useful for API's which was token based authentication, obviously API's are not part of their roadmap!

I used the guidance in the article referenced above to create my own JSON only Warden strategy that uses an OAUTH 2 Owner Password Credentials Grant type (See [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)) to generate and return a bearer token for use on future API requests. API clients can easily create the JSON to do this kind of authentication to obtain an authorization access token.

I will provide some of the Rails code to get you started below, but you will have to integrate into your specific environment. No warranty offered :)

Warden initializer:

```
# config/initializers/warden.rb
Dir["./app/strategies/warden/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :null_auth, :oauth_access_token, :oauth_owner_password
  manager.failure_app = UnauthorizedController
end
```

Warden strategy for OAUTH 2 password authentication:

```
# app/strategies/warden/oauth_owner_password_strategy.rb
module Warden
  class OauthOwnerPasswordStrategy < Strategies::Base
    def valid?
      return false if request.get?

      params['grant_type'] == 'password' && params['client_id'] == 'web' && ! params['username'].blank?
    end

    def authenticate!
      user = User.with_login(params['username']).first
      if user.nil? || user.confirmed_at.nil? || ! user.authenticate!(params['password'])
        # delay failures for up to 20ms to thwart timing based attacks
        sleep(SecureRandom.random_number(20) / 1000.0)
        fail! :message => 'strategies.password.failed'
      else
        success! user, store: false
      end

      # ADD HERE: log IP and timestamp of all authentication attempts
    end
  end

  Strategies.add(:oauth_owner_password, OauthOwnerPasswordStrategy)
end
```

Warden strategy for OAUTH 2 access token authentication:

```
# app/strategies/warden/oauth_access_token_strategy.rb
module Warden
  class OauthAccessTokenStrategy < Strategies::Base
    def valid?
      # must be a bearer token
      return false unless auth_header = request.headers['authorization']
      auth_header.split(' ')[0] == 'Bearer'
    end

    def authenticate!
      # Use a periodic cleaner instead
      # clean out all old tokens. DOES NOT RUN CALLBACKS!
      Token.expired.delete

      # lookup bearer token
      token = Token.active.first(purpose: 'access', token: request.headers['authorization'].split(' ')[1])
      if token && (user = token.user) && user.confirmed_at
        success! user, store: false
      else
        # delay failures for up to 20ms to thwart timing based attacks
        sleep(SecureRandom.random_number(20) / 1000.0)
        fail! message: 'strategies.oauth_access_token.failed'
      end
    end
  end

  Strategies.add(:oauth_access_token, OauthAccessTokenStrategy)
end
```

Null authentication strategy (can be useful in development, just set `config.null_auth_user` within config/environments/development.rb):

```
# app/strategies/warden/null_auth_strategy.rb
module Warden
  class NullAuthStrategy < Strategies::Base
    def valid?
      ! Rails.configuration.null_auth_user.blank?
    end

    def authenticate!
      user = User.with_login(params["username"]||Rails.configuration.null_auth_user).first
      if user.nil?
        fail! :message => "strategies.password.failed"
      else
        success! user, store: false
      end
    end
  end

  Strategies.add(:null_auth, NullAuthStrategy)
end
```

Warden failure application for JSON clients (uses a bare metal rails controller):

```
# app/controllers/unauthorized_controller.rb
class UnauthorizedController < ActionController::Metal

  def self.call(env)
    @respond ||= action(:respond)
    @respond.call(env)
  end

  def respond(env)
    self.status = 401
    self.content_type = 'json'
    self.response_body = { 'errors' => ['Authentication failure']}.to_json
  end
end
```

Add the following in your base API controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate!

protected

    helper_method :warden, :signed_in?, :current_user

    def warden
      request.env['warden']
    end

    def signed_in?
      !current_user.nil?
    end

    def current_user
      @current_user ||= warden.user
    end

    def authenticate!(*args)
      warden.authenticate!(*args)
      # ADD ANY POST AUTHENTICATION SETUP CODE HERE
    end
```

A sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApiController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate!

  # TODO exceptions and errors should return unauthorized HTTP response.
  # see RFC for details

  def create
    # mandate the password strategy.
    # don't use session store (don't want session cookies on APIs)
    authenticate!(scope: :oauth_owner_password, store: false)

    if signed_in?
      # create access token
      token = Token.create! purpose: 'access',
                            user: current_user,
                            expires_in: Rails.configuration.session_lifetime

       # Ensure response is never cached
       response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-store"
       response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
       response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"

      # send the OAuth response
      render json: {
          access_token: token.token,
          token_type: 'Bearer',
          expires_in: token.expires_in,
          scope: 'user'
      }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Token.current.delete
    warden.logout
    head :no_content
  end
end
```

You will need to define your own User and Token models for tracking users and bearer tokens respectively, the Token model needs to have a scope called `active` to limit the result set to unexpired tokens. Token generation should use `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`

Comment: Andrew, this is great.  For those looking for example models, the Devise User model is a good start (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/active_record/devise_generator.rb) but a sample Token model would really help this example.  Could you include one, Andrew?

Comment: I was trying to be ORM agnostic as not everyone (including myself) uses ActiveRecord but I will update when I get some  time to include some sample models for Sequel and AR but AR will be untested.

Comment: @AndrewHacking - great solution!! Thanks for posting! Following up on this, would you mind sharing an example of your AR Token model?

Answer (score 10):

When you say Web app server and a separate API server, which needs to talk to each other every time there is an update from a user on your Web app server. All I can suggest you to break them down to 3 entities as rails engine.

1. Core: Which will hold all your Model and your data logic.
2. Application: Which will depend on your core engine and have client facing code, mostly controllers and views.
3. API: Which will again depend on your core engine and have processing logic, API controllers maybe.

Why Core? Because, when you need to update your business logic, it will be just one place: Core Engine.

Now to answer your question further on authenticating API call from your web app server. You need to:

1. Build the API - [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem?view=asciicast) and [Building Awesome Rails APIS from Collective Idea Blog](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2013/06/13/building-awesome-rails-apis-part-1/).
2. Secure the API - [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast) and [Looking for suggestions for building a secure REST API within Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247110/looking-for-suggestions-for-building-a-secure-rest-api-within-ruby-on-rails).
3. I prefer OAuth for securing the API calls. For implementing OAuth2 in rails you can use [doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper).

Once you're done with securing API, you can implement the authentication logic in your Web application. You can use [OAuth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) for authenticating your app from API.

Also, to make your API available only to OAuth calls using doorkeeper: https://doorkeeper-provider.herokuapp.com/#client-applications

P.S.: I prefer json response from the APIs, it's a preferred trend I'd say. ;)

**EDIT-** [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) is a chrome extension for making experimental/fake APIs before you actually write them for your application. It's much faster because you'd know what you finally have to design at the end of the day.

Answer (score 5):

Usually it works like this. Your app issues a secret token for every user (it can be for example a md5 hash, it's long, and it's quite random). Token should be kept safe by user. You can do that by following two rules:
- never disclose token publicly (all requests should be made from backend, no AJAX calls etc.)
- all requests should be made over https, so they are encrypted

Reason to use token instead of username & password? In case token is compromised you can revoke it and user still has control over they account. Also, with token-based authentication certain operations like changing email or password associated with account should not be possible.

Token should be passed as a param with each request done to your API.

Comment: Could you please explain "all requests should be made from backend" (Any resource from where I can read mere about it). Also if the user wants to allow some other service provider to access it's data, should I implement it using OAuth2 and API Key?

Comment: Secret key in my example is just like password. And you don't pub passwords in publicly available code, right? You can do OAuth but this is more complicated (and also this is something I never did so not gonna pretend I have any idea how to set up OAuth 2 server)

Answer (score 0):

If you to build json, xml based api, use rabl gem https://github.com/nesquena/rabl.

For simpler authentication, go for session based authentication which rails provided with session variable in controller. If you want neat, some function for user, then go for authologic gem https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.

If you want complete user management , then go for devise gem.

Answer (score -4):

Rails uses sessions to keep track of the state of a user, which is stored in the user's cookies.

The documentation for sessions can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions)

If you leverage an authentication system such as [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), you will have access to a current_user method in your controllers as well as a ton of different helpers which you can leverage, depending on your specific needs

Comment: how does it answer OP?